# How to tell if your spark job is waiting for resources

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark job that I submit to a standalone spark cluster - this is an auto scaling cluster on ec2 boxes so when jobs are submitted and not enough nodes are available, after a few minutes a few more boxes spin up and become available.

We have a @timeout decorator on the main part of the spark job to timeout and error when it's exceeded a certain time threshold (put in place because of some jobs hanging). The issue is that sometimes a job may not have gotten to actually starting because its waiting on resources yet @timeout function is evaluated and jobs error out as a result.

So I'm wondering if there's anyway to tell from within the application itself, with code, if the job is waiting for resources?

Answer (score 0):

To know the status of the application then you need to access the Spark Job History server from where you can get the current status of the job.

**You can solve your problem as follows:**

1. Get Application ID of your job through **sc.applicationId**.
2. Then use this application Id with Spark History Server REST APIs to get the status of the submitted job.
   You can find the Spark History Server Rest APIs at [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/monitoring.html).